# Clip .hdf (MODIS) rasters by shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, modis

I am trying to do a temporal analysis on vegetation quality so I downloaded a MODIS .hds raster from earthexplorer.
When I opened the file into ArcMap 10.2.2, it came as a group of 11 rasters.
I stuck on clipping those rasters by my shapefile and combining them into one. (tried, clip raster by shapefile, composite bands...)

Answer (score 1):

Clipping *.hdf files in ArcGIS may not be a good idea as ArcGIS doesn't deal with HDF files very well. I would recommend you convert the HDF files into some other formats (eg, tif) first and then clip them in ArcGIS.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the kind answer. I found this little tool called Modis Reprojection Tool, that helped me with MODIS data instead. It can be found here: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool